# Text and image, side by side, in footnote

Tags: graphics, footnotes

I would like to have the text of my footnote on the left of an image.

I've tried:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
Some text\footnote{\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{r}{.5\textwidth}
The text of my footnote.
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{images/f1-n.pdf}
\end{wrapfigure}
}
\end{document}
```

But the text of the note and the relative number are not on the same line.

Also I've tried:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
Some text\footnote{\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\linewidth}
The text of my footnote.
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{images/f1-n.pdf}
\end{minipage}%
}
\end{document}
```

but this give me worse results.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need `wrapfigure`?  Or would text on left/image on right be sufficient?

Comment: It's sufficient to have the image on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to add a caption, it's simple with the `insbox` plain TeX macro package. The `\InsertBoxR` command takes two arguments: the number of lines *not* shortened at the beginning of the paragraph, and th object inserted, plus an optional argument, the number of supplementary lines to be shortened, in case TeX does not calculate the correct number of necessary lines.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{lipsum}%
\input{insbox}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{30\baselineskip}
Some text\footnote{\vskip-\baselineskip\InsertBoxR{0}{\includegraphics{droopyhappybeer}}\hskip0.8em Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at, tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy pellentesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin fermentum massa ac quam. Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat magna. Nunc eleifend consequat lorem. Sed lacinia nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque tincidunt purus vel magna. In teger non enim. Praesent euismod nunc eu purus. Donec bibendum quam in tellus. Nullam cursus pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi. Nam vulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulum pellentesque felis eu massa.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Never heard of `insbox`.  That's very neat!

Comment: It's often very useful when `wrapfig` doe not work (e.g. in the neighbourhood of lists).

Comment: Wow. Very simple. I notice that now it's required also an horizontal control with the command \hskip0.8em.

Comment: It comes from the fact that `\InsertBoxR` has to be set before a paragraph begins. This makes the footnote text begin  at the line *under* the footnote mark (whence `\vskip-\baselineskip`), and we have to compensate for the label width (this may depend on the document class).

Comment: @Bernard If you replace `\vspace*{30\baselineskip}` by `\lipsum[1]` in your code and add `\lipsum[1]` after the footnote, you obtain a strange effect (see question [Wrong spacing generated by a footnote image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/496866/132405)).

Answer (score 2):

This does not allow `wrapfigure` like behavior, but allows one to place text on left and image on right of the footnote.  The image width can be adjusted to suit the text height, perhaps.  The `\hfill` between them assures that the image is right-aligned to the margin.

The `\parbox` has to be top `[t]` aligned to match up with the footnote marker.  As a result, the `\includegraphics` has to be shifted down an amount equal to `\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox`, so that the top of the image aligns to the text.

EDITED to handle left margin issue, by introducing `\def\fngap{15pt}` and adding a negative `\hspace` of it prior to the `\parbox`, and a positive `\hspace` of it inside the `\parbox`.  Also, I added a `\strut` at the end of the footnote text (in the `\parbox`) to make sure the spacing to the 2nd footnote was correct.  (I am sure `\fngap` corresponds to some LaTeX measure of footnote indent, perhaps as simple as `\parindent`.  But that value must be captured before going into the `\footnote`, so one could have said `\edef\fngap{\the\parindent}` instead of `\def\fngap{15pt}`.)

EDITED again to provide macro

```
\withfig{<text-fraction>}{<text>}{<image-fraction>}{<image-filename>}
```

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\fngap{15pt}
\newcommand\withfig[4]{%
\hspace{-\fngap}\parbox[t]{#1\textwidth}{\hspace{\fngap}%
  #2\strut}\hfill%
\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox}{%
  \includegraphics[width=#3\textwidth]{#4}}%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
Some text\footnote{\withfig{.5}{\lipsum[4]Last part of footnote}{.4}{example-image}}
%
\footnote{\lipsum[4]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Steven. Is it possible to have the second line of the text under the footnote number, as for footnote with only text?

Comment: @Torpedo See revision.

Comment: Yes. This is what I was trying to get even if it's a little bit "complicated". I was hoping in less commands or in some package.

Comment: @Torpedo I have converted it into a 4-parameter macro.