# Wrong spacing generated by a footnote image

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, footnotes

I wrote the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\input{insbox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] Why?\footnote{
                         \InsertBoxL{0}{ \qquad \includegraphics[height=3cm]{t}}
                         \hskip0.8em 
                         \lipsum[1]}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

such that to insert a photo, in a footnote, which is surrounded by text as in the following picture

[image]

What is the reason that an invisible wrap photo was inserted in the text block? If I move the photo to the left, I will get the same undesirable aligment. Could someone provide another example of how can one insert a photo in a footnote?

P.S. The content of the insbox.tex can be found at the following link 
[insbox.tex](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/insbox) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quote from the insbox documentation:-

> " I do not guarrantee [sic] correct behaviour of these macros in other
>   extreme conditions"

Furthermore the package says **"within paragraphs"** (There are no examples of use in footnotes).

You have asked for working alternative, so I offer this

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum,mwe}
%\input{insbox} % appears to use undesirable cutspace approach in a paragraph
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\textbf{Why? hello world\footnote{\begin{wrapfigure}{l}[-5pt]{6cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}}\end{wrapfigure}Hello World \lipsum[1]
}\lipsum[66]}

\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```